# Compare two boolean lists using Python

Tags: python, lambda, boolean

```
is_it_equal_func_1 = lambda x:x in list1
is_it_equal_list_2 = map(is_it_equal_func_1, list2)
print(list(is_it_equal_list_2))
# prints [True, True, True, True, True]

is_it_equal_func_3 = lambda y:y in list3
is_it_equal_list_4 = map(is_it_equal_func_3, list1)
print(list(is_it_equal_list_4))
# prints [True, True, True, True, True]
```

How to compare each boolean values incase I get `False` in one of the lists?

Tried:

```
is_it_equal_func_5 = lambda y:y in str(list(is_it_equal_list_2))
is_it_equal_func_6 = map(is_it_equal_func_5, list(is_it_equal_list_4))
print(list(is_it_equal_func_6))
# prints [True, True]
# I want [True, True, True, True, True]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the below method to compare two lists and get the boolean list of results. The below answer will work even if the two lists are not of the same size. Use `itertools.zip_longest` for Python 3.x

```
import itertools

alist = [1,2,3,4]
blist = [3,2,5]

compare_list = [(a == b) for a,b in itertools.izip_longest(alist, blist)]

print compare_list
```

**Output:**

```
[False, True, False, False]
```

Comment: Got ```AttributeError: module 'itertools' has no attribute 'izip_longest'```

Comment: Use zip_longest for Python 3.x

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for 'zip':

```
results = [(v1 == v2) for v1,v2 in zip(list1, list2)]
print(results)
```

(untested)

Comment: Returns ```[]``` empty list